# How do I eliminate the not relevant outputs of my code?

Tags: ruby

This is my code so far:

```
class Integer
  def atm
    money =  %w[e500 e200 e100 e50 e20 e10 e5]
    return '' if self == 0    
    money.each do |m|        
      value = m.split('e').last.to_i    
      next if self.to_f / value < 1.0    
      anm = self / value
      erg = ("e" + value.to_s)
      return money << {erg => anm}, (self-anm*value).atm
      end
  end
end

puts 140.atm
```

It gives this output:

e500
e200
e100
e50
e20
e10
e5
{"e100"=>1}
e500
e200
e100
e50
e20
e10
e5
{"e20"=>2}

But I just want this:

```
[{ "e100" => 1 },{ "e20" => 2 }]
```

How can I eliminate the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the desired *output* by removing `money <<` from your `return` statement, i.e.:

```
return {erg => anm}, (self-anm*value).atm
```

Which gives:

```
puts 140.atm
{"e100"=>1}
{"e20"=>2}
```

However, `puts` hides the fact that the *result* is actually a nested array with an empty string:

```
p 140.atm
[{"e100"=>1}, [{"e20"=>2}, ""]]
```

To fix this, you can return `nil` if `self` is `0`:

```
return nil if self == 0

# or simply

return if self == 0
```

And use the splat operator `*` on the second element for `return` to "flatten" the return value:

```
return {erg => anm}, *(self-anm*value).atm
#                    ^
```

Which gives:

```
p 140.atm
[{"e100"=>1}, {"e20"=>2}]
```

---

Another option is to avoid the recursion and to collect the result within the loop, e.g.:

```
def atm
  money =  %w[e500 e200 e100 e50 e20 e10 e5]

  i = self
  money.each_with_object([]) do |m, result|
    value = m.split('e').last.to_i
    anm, i = i.divmod(value)
    result << { m => anm } if anm > 0
  end
end
```

I'm using `divmod` here to calculate the quotient and remainder (actually the modulus) at once. It works like this:

```
140.divmod(500) #=> [0, 140]
140.divmod(200) #=> [0, 140]
140.divmod(100) #=> [1,  40]
 40.divmod( 50) #=> [0,  40]
 40.divmod( 20) #=> [2,   0]
```

The result's first element determines who many times the arguments "fits" into the receiver. Its second element is the remainder which also becomes the new left-hand value.

For example:

```
140.divmod(100) #=> [1,  40]
# means: 140 = 100 * 1 + 40
```

Answer (score 2):

**Object to be returned**

You may find it more convenient to return a hash rather than an array of hashes. For example,

```
645.atm
  #=> { 500=>1, 200=>0, 100=>1, 50=>0, 20=>2, 10=>0, 5=>1 }  
0.atm
  #=> { 500=>0, 200=>0, 100=>0, 50=>0, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0 }
```

unless there is no way to convert the given amount to different amounts of the given denominations, in which case `nil` is returned:

```
646.atm
  #=> nil
```

I assume that, before `Integer#atm` is called, it has been  confirmed that the amount to be changed (`self`) is a non-negative integer.

**`Integer#atm` method**

We may write:

```
class Integer
  def atm
    denominations = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]
    change = denominations.product([0]).to_h
    amount_to_change = self
    denominations.each do |d|
      change[d], amount_to_change = amount_to_change.divmod(d)
      return change if amount_to_change.zero?
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

See [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product), [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) and [Integer#divmod](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-divmod), the latter being a very useful, yet underutilized, method.

**Try it**

Let's try it, but first I will add some `puts` statements to illustrate the intermediate calculations.

```
class Integer
  def atm
    denominations = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]
    change = denominations.product([0]).to_h
    puts "change=#{change}"
    amount_to_change = self
    puts "Initial amount_to_change=#{amount_to_change}"
    denominations.each do |d|
      change[d], amount_to_change = amount_to_change.divmod(d)
      puts "d=#{d}, change=#{change}, amount_to_change=#{amount_to_change}"
      return change if amount_to_change.zero?
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

```
645.atm
change={500=>0, 200=>0, 100=>0, 50=>0, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0}
Initial amount_to_change=645
d=500, change={500=>1, 200=>0, 100=>0, 50=>0, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0}, amount_to_change=145
d=200, change={500=>1, 200=>0, 100=>0, 50=>0, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0}, amount_to_change=145
d=100, change={500=>1, 200=>0, 100=>1, 50=>0, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0}, amount_to_change=45
d=50, change={500=>1, 200=>0, 100=>1, 50=>0, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0}, amount_to_change=45
d=20, change={500=>1, 200=>0, 100=>1, 50=>0, 20=>2, 10=>0, 5=>0}, amount_to_change=5
d=10, change={500=>1, 200=>0, 100=>1, 50=>0, 20=>2, 10=>0, 5=>0}, amount_to_change=5
d=5, change={500=>1, 200=>0, 100=>1, 50=>0, 20=>2, 10=>0, 5=>1}, amount_to_change=0
  #=> {500=>1, 200=>0, 100=>1, 50=>0, 20=>2, 10=>0, 5=>1}
```

```
0.atm
change={500=>0, 200=>0, 100=>0, 50=>0, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0}
Initial amount_to_change=0
  #=> {500=>0, 200=>0, 100=>0, 50=>0, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0}
```

```
646.atm
change={500=>0, 200=>0, 100=>0, 50=>0, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0}
Initial amount_to_change=646
d=500, change={500=>1, 200=>0, 100=>0, 50=>0, 20=>0, 10=>0, 5=>0}, amount_to_change=146
...
d=5, change={500=>1, 200=>0, 100=>1, 50=>0, 20=>2, 10=>0, 5=>1}, amount_to_change=1
  #=> nil
```

**Make code more *Ruby-like* by using `Enumerable#each_with_object`**

You will find that the method [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) is widely used in Ruby code. Here it would be used as follows.

```
class Integer
  def atm
    denominations = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]
    amount_to_change = self
    denominations.each_with_object(denominations.product([0]).to_h) do |d,change|
      change[d], amount_to_change = amount_to_change.divmod(d)
      return change if amount_to_change.zero?
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

**Use a default value for hash keys**

Another change you might consider is use [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) to define the hash to have a *default value* of zero:

```
change = Hash.new(0)
  #=> {}
```

This merely causes `change[k]` to return `0` when the hash has no key `k`. The hash is not altered:

```
change[500]
  #=> 0
change
  #=> {}
change[500] = 1
change
  #=> {500=>1}
```

We may now change the method `atm` as follows.

```
class Integer
  def atm
    denominations = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]
    amount_to_change = self
    puts "Initial amount to change=#{amount_to_change}"
    denominations.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |d,change|
      chg, amount_to_change = amount_to_change.divmod(d)
      change[d] = chg if chg > 0
      puts "d=#{d}, change=#{change}, amount_to_change=#{amount_to_change}"
      return change if amount_to_change.zero?
   end
   nil
  end
end
```

```
645.atm
Initial amount to change=645
d=500, change={500=>1}, amount_to_change=145
d=200, change={500=>1}, amount_to_change=145
d=100, change={500=>1, 100=>1}, amount_to_change=45
d=50, change={500=>1, 100=>1}, amount_to_change=45
d=20, change={500=>1, 100=>1, 20=>2}, amount_to_change=5
d=10, change={500=>1, 100=>1, 20=>2}, amount_to_change=5
d=5, change={500=>1, 100=>1, 20=>2, 5=>1}, amount_to_change=0
  #=> {500=>1, 100=>1, 20=>2, 5=>1}
```

If we compute `change = 645.atm`, and need the number of units of a given denomination we simply write, for example,

```
change[500]
  #=> 1
change[50]
  #=> 0 (default value)
```

We must be mindful, however, that

```
change["cat"]
  #=> 0
```

**Avoid polluting the core class `Integer`**

[Monkey patching](https://wiki.c2.com/?MonkeyPatching)--adding or changing core methods--is generally frowned upon. Better to write, for example,

```
def atm(amount_to_change)
  denominations = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]
  denominations.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |d,change|
    chg, amount_to_change = amount_to_change.divmod(d)
    change[d] = chg if chg > 0
    return change if amount_to_change.zero?
  end
  nil
end
```

Another option is to use [Refinements](https://medium.com/rubycademy/refine-and-using-methods-in-ruby-part-i-2aef6d7a4325).

Comment: You don't really need a default value for the hash – `each_with_object({})` works just fine.

Comment: To elaborate @Stefan's comment, suppose `change = 500.atm #=> { 500=>1 }`. Then `change[5] #=> 0`. If I were to use `each_with_object({})`, `change` would be the same (no key `5`), so `change[5] #=> nil`. To determine the number of `5` unit denominations I therefore would need to write `change.key?(5) ? change[5] : 0`,`change[5].to_i` or `change.fetch(5,0)`, in the latter case `0` being the value returned if `change` has no key `5`. It's really a matter of personal preference whether `Hash.new(0)` or `{}` is used.